# JFace: Setgrayed don't work in treeviewer

Tags: java, eclipse, treeview, swt, jface

I want to disable (only virtual) some specific nodes in my treeviewer, but it seems to have no effect on my nodes. I also tried to set an backgound which also don't work. Any ideas on this?

```
private void setSelectedElements(TreeItem[] treeItems) {
        for (TreeItem item : treeItems) {
            Object obj = item.getData();
            if (item.getParentItem() != null) {
                Object parentElement = item.getParentItem().getData();
                if (parentElement instanceof Mandatory) {
                    setChecked(item);
                    Display display = Display.getCurrent();
                    item.setGrayed(true);
                    item.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
                }
            }
            setSelectedElements(item.getItems());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`setGrayed` is used to change the state of a check box in a check box tree or table. It does not change the tree item color. From the JavaDoc for `setGrayed`:

> Sets the grayed state of the checkbox for this item. This state change only applies if the Tree was created with the SWT.CHECK style.

If you want to change the color of a tree item use a `LabelProvider` which implements `IColorProvider` or a label provider derived from `StyledCellLabelProvider`.

Comment: Hi, ok IColorProvider has worked, but what happen if I want to check the state of other nodes. For example I checked Node A and Node B should change the color. Therefor a Labelprovider don't fit in and item.setBackground() is neccessary.

Comment: Call `TreeViewer.update` or `refresh` on the objects that change and the label provider will be called

Comment: Hmm, I've some complex dependencies between nodes and it would be too complex to manage this all in the labelprovider. I'ld rather prefer the class containing my TreeViewer as playce to change the backgroundcolor, but this don't work..I Maybe create a new question for this